# Post Data from One PHP File to Another Gives Error

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two php files, one file submits data to a second file for an update action into mysql database.

below is the code for the file that submits data

```html
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name 
$server_name="localhost";


// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name , 3306);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}  

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";

$result = $con->query($sql);

$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();          

?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection 
$con->close();
?>
```

the second file for the update action is presented below

```html
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name 
$server_name="localhost";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name , 3306);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}  

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name', lastname='$lastname', email='$email' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=$con->query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

the error page is presented below.
[image]

An suggestions to fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you haven't set those values yet that's why it's getting an error.
First you must wrap your second file to check if it has submitted the form. Then set those variables inside.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $id = $_POST['id'];

  // rest of your code goes here
}
```

Comment: thanks but can you explain why we need to set the values. Pardon am new to php

Comment: @faisalabdulai Yes, because it needs to know which is which and it doesn't automatically set it by itself even if you call the same name(e.g `$lastname`). So when you submit a form, the values set are being passed to the target file and stored inside a `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 1):

Make changes to your second file as

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $id = $_POST['id'];
// add you rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define some variables before line

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name', lastname='$lastname', email='$email' WHERE id='$id'";
```

For example

```
$tbl_name = 'mytable';
$name = 'ABC';
$lastname = 'XYZ';
$email = 'abc@example.com';
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name', lastname='$lastname', email='$email' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second file where you write sql query to update data,
You are using :-

**undefine variable**
`name, lastname, email, id`

get posted value in these variable like that, before sql query:-

```
 $name= $_POST['name'];
 $lastname= $_POST['lastname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

User this at top of your request page.

```
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $id=$_POST['id'];
```